# Getting number of rows form SQL Server table

Tags: php, sql-server, count

I have a problem with getting the right value after I counted the rows from a table. I searched on the web but didn't find an answer.

In the database i have a table with all the categories in it they all have an id, and i would like to count using this column.

I have this PHP code, it works but is there an other and better to get over this?

```
    $sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM categories";
    $stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql2);
    $res = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($res as $row)
    {
        $rows = $row;
    }

    //if there are categories display them otherwise don't
    if ($rows > 0)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<a href='#' class='cat_links'>" . $row['category_name'] . "  - <font size='-1'>" . $row['category_description'] . "</font></a>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<p style='text-align: center'>No categories yet.</p>";
    }
```

I think has to be a better way to convert the $stmt2 variable from a SQL resource to an actual number, or to convert the $res variable from an array to an number. If I try to echo the whole array using foreach, it will only print out the number of rows. This is why I use it to count the rows now.

I can't use the sqlsrv_num_rows function because I then get an error, or no answer.

Comment: What was the error you got?

Comment: It said it was a dynamic table I think, but I don't get it all the time and I don't have the code which produces the error anymore, if I now use sqlsrv_num_rows i don't get anything

Comment: the number of rows for a `COUNT()` query would be 1. Did you do that are just return the rows you needed?

Comment: I need to get the number of rows from the table, it will differ if I add categories to it, it wont be 1 for ever

Comment: `COUNT()` will return a single number in a single row.

Comment: COUNT(Column_name) does return the number of rows in a column?

Comment: You can write the Query Like as follows.

$sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS no_of_rows FROM categories";

Then can get the number of rows ($no_of_rows = $res['no_of_rows'];)

Comment: use sqlsrv_fetch and sqlsrv_get_field (see the example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch.php )

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks Pravat Kumar Sahoo!